# Add a character to the mid of a string that is not always the same

Tags: c#, string, console-application

In my program I need to add a character to my string and then print it on the console. In my case, the number will not be always the same, but will always have 2 characters. I need to add a ' , ' to the mid position, but I don't know how. (I'm very beginner, please post an example code).
An example is, I want to turn "25" to "2,5". Thanks for your help.
[sorry for bad english, also the title can be pretty bad/misleading]

Comment: Look up "c-sharp SubString" and "C-sharp IndexOf" and try something. If you get stuck on something in particular, share the code you've tried and the specific problem you are having.

Comment: By chance are you trying to format the string for a regional currency?

Comment: what do you mean by "the number will not be always equals"?

Comment: @YakovL He means the number will not be always `25` but will always have 2 characters.

Comment: i mean, the number "will not be always the same". sorry about that

Comment: @S.Akbari Thank you for explaining it, and sorry for my error.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your requirement (*will always have 2 characters*) You can use [`Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Like this:

```
string str = "25";
string result = str.Insert(1, ",");//2.5
```

But if it has more than 2 characters you can append the `,` in the middle of the string like this:

```
string str = "25";
string result = str.Insert(str.Length / 2, ",");//2.5
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining me. By the way, it worked :)