# How can I insert a word at the first space in a line in c#?

Tags: c#, insert, indexof

I have a string like following,

```
string myline="public methodname(parameters)";
```

How can I insert a new string, like "static" at the first occurence space, that is between public and methodname.
Note that the first word and second word of my string can be anything. And I want to insert a string at the first space in my string.

so my output will be like

`public static methodname(parameters)`

I have used, Insert and IndexOf methods. But I cannot get the exact result. Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497314/add-a-character-to-the-mid-of-a-string-that-is-not-always-the-same

Comment: "I have used, Insert and IndexOf methods" if you would post the code that you tried, that would make your question round and sound. would be worth an upvote for a well posted question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this, I haven't tested previous version of the code, follow should be OK.

```
String myline = "Public something";
int pos = myline.IndexOf(" ");
if(pos < 0)
{
  //Error
}
String stringYouWant = myline.Substring(0, pos) + " static " + myline.Substring(pos +1);
Console.WriteLine(stringYouWant);
```

Comment: @fubo check this out

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
string myline = "public methodname(parameters)";
string result = myline.Insert(myline.IndexOf(' '), " static");
```

Comment: Much faster than me, Great

Comment: But if my string is like `public string methodname(parameters)` I guess it will insert at every space. How to insert  only at the first space in my string?

Comment: @Vishwaroopa no, IndexOf returns only the index of the first occurrence. Check out the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please help me in trimimg the space before "public" incase if it is present? Because if there is space before `public`, then my result would be like `static public methodname(parameters)`

Comment: @Vishwaroopa not part of the initial question - but you can use `" public".TrimStart()`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string myline = "public methodname(parameters)"; 
string result = myline.Replace("public ", "public static ")
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G2sw3y)

Comment: @MongZhu then  "myline.Replace("public ", "public static ");"  this would help

Answer (score 1):

```
Example:
string s = "Dot Net ";
string v = s.Replace("Net", "Basket");
```